# Share real time Data From Viewpager Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have Fragments with a play button in my fragment. Whenever the user presses the play button from the `ViewPager` fragment, it calls a function in host activity which plays the player.

I am trying to implement the live data by using a `ViewModel` but unsuccessful.

```
public class SlidePlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide_player, container, false);

        ImageView playBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewModel.getIsPlaying().setValue(true);
                viewModel.getCheck().setValue("Checking");
            }
        });
        return view;
       }
    }
}
```

Here's my `PagerAdapter`

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int pages;
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int count) {
        super(fm);
        pages = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new SlidePlayerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages;
    }
}
```

Here is the view model function

```
private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isPlaying;

public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getIsPlaying() {
    if (isPlaying == null)
        isPlaying = new MutableLiveData<>();
    Log.d("TAG","Checking "+isPlaying.getValue());
    return isPlaying;
}
```

And here is the observer segment

```
final Observer<Boolean> isPlaying= isPlaying -> {
    //code here if playing then do some task here
};

viewModel.getIsPlaying().observe(this,isPlaying);
```

**Note** I already tried to find the predefined solution but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I dont see any place you create your `ViewModel` and use it in your activity. Can you update your code?

Comment: updated @KingfisherPhuoc

Answer (score 0):

You do not really have to have a `ViewModel` for this purpose. You might just consider having `public` functions in the `Activity` which hosts the `Fragments`. For example, let us consider you have the following `public` functions in your `PlayerActivity` which launches all the other fragments.

```
public void play(String songName) {
    viewModel.getIsPlaying().setValue(true);
    viewModel.getCheck().setValue("Checking");
    // Other actions for playing
}
```

Now, you might just consider the following `onClick` function instead of the one you are having now.

```
playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((PlayerActivity) getActivity()).play(songName);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, it may be help. is there's any chances ((MyActivity) getActivity()) returns null?? studio showing me null pointer exception warning. is there any drawback if i use an instance of my activity(public and static) then through that instance i access my activity functions?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no chance of having a NullPointerException. However, if there's a chance you can easily avoid the crash by checking for the null value. Yes, you can have a static function as well that matches your application design.

Comment: well i found the solution with this code :D i was using 'this' keyword for initialization of MyViewModel class inside the Fragment but it should be getActivity(). my bad i ma so silly.BTW thanks for your help #Murshed